# How to Take Average of Data Within a Column to create new Variable

Tags: sql, r, database, dataframe, transpose

I have a simple task which I cannot wrap my head around being a novice coder.

I have a data set which I am trying to manipulate.

It appears as this:

```
UniqueID Day Var AverageVar
1        1   X
1        2   Y
1        3   Z
2        1   A
2        2   B
2        3   C
```

I would like to create this new "AverageVar" variable which computes an average across the three days for each unique ID.

So, for example, the AverageVar for the first three rows I would like to create and have (X + Y + Z)/3 displayed. Is there any easy code for this in SQL or R?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Ah, I forgot all the basics! Group by the UniqueID and then average across days? I'll try that...

Comment: In R, you can do `aggregate(DayVar~UniqueID,df, mean)` OR `with(df, ave(DayVar, UniqueID))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * INTO newtable
FROM 
(SELECT UniqueID, AVG(Var) as AverageVar
FROM table
GROUP BY UniqueID);

SELECT O.UniqueID, O.Day, O.Var, N.AverageVar
FROM oldtable O
INNER JOIN
newtable N
ON O.UniqueID = N.UniqueID;
```